# What is the neurological mechanism behind the feelings associated with loneliness?

Tags: social-psychology, neuroscience, emotion

Loneliness can be debilitating, and the feelings associated with it can be overwhelming, including feeling 'cold inside', sad, hopeless and even helpless.

Many things can 'cause' loneliness', both real and perceived, but what I am interested in is not the causes, but the neurological mechanisms that cause the feelings associated with loneliness.